# What is Blackmart, and is it legitimate?

Tags: applications, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I have an HTC One X. I want to install the Blackmart app, but I'm a little wary about its implications. Can it safely be installed without it messing up root security? Is it a legitimate app source?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Even if the pure Blackmart App is free of any malicious parts, there is still the danger that you will download an infected version. Blackmart has no official page or download site, that's why you can't be sure about that. It's even worse because it needs *root*. Those types of programs are usually not open-source, and therefore no one can review the code or even build a "clean" version.

Note: Since Blackmark is able to bypass the access restrictions for paid Apps, it's is *illegal* in some countries. This is likely true in all countries where Google sells Apps on the Play Store.

**My personal opinion: A free game of Modern Warefare or GTA isn't worth the trouble and risk of using blackmart.**

Comment: And if blackmart wasn't risky enough the apps could be modified too.

Comment: Almost all paid games from bigger publishers employ some sort of copy protection. Those have to be modified to circumvent he protection schemes. Besides the legal implications you don't know what else was modified and if a malware infection is the real price for 'loading stuff for free'. That's by the way how most of the malware is beeing distributed.

Comment: Having never used it, I went and tried it out on a free game (that is also available from Play Store). The only necessity of superuser access is when you install the app you downloaded through Blackmart, because your installing an app that didnt come from the Play Store (Google security measures). Its not justBlackmart, but all 3rd party app sites where malicious apps could be. The biggest form of "malware" seems abundantly amassed right within the Play Store itself, all the apps loaded with ads and broadcast intents. The bottom line is be responsible i n your quest for apps.

Comment: You don't need root in Android in order to install Apps from non Play Store places ("unknown sources").

Comment: @Flow that's when you use the inbuilt package installer. But Blackmart install app without package manager.

Comment: An interesting article here which highlights the potential issues: https://www.techjunkie.com/what-is-blackmart-alpha/